# Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, usando coroutines - Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, corrutinas

estoy intentando descargar una archivo almacenado en el almacenamiento de firebase y lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma:

```
    fun downloadSong(v: View) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val storereference = v.tag as StorageReference

            storereference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<Any?> {
                try {
                    val u = URL(it.toString())
                    val conn: URLConnection = u.openConnection()
                    val contentLength: Int = conn.getContentLength()
                    val stream = DataInputStream(u.openStream())
                    val buffer = ByteArray(contentLength)
                    stream.readFully(buffer)
                    stream.close()
                    val fos = DataOutputStream(FileOutputStream(MediaStore.Downloads.DOWNLOAD_URI))
                    fos.write(buffer)
                    fos.flush()
                    fos.close()

                } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                    return@OnSuccessListener  // swallow a 404
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    return@OnSuccessListener  // swallow a 404
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener {
                // Handle any errors
            })
        }
    }
```

En un principio no usaba las coroutines, hasta que me salio el error de " `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`". Aún usando la coroutine me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, como si estuviese ejecutando la descarga en el MainThread, cuando el realidad no es así. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Un saludo.

Comment: Si, olvide "aceptar la respuesta", me sirvió mucho, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: por qué creaste otro usuario? No respondí la pregunta de la carpeta descarga porque no vi ningún esfuerzo de tu parte y tampoco la otra por ser un usuario falso. Ahora que te has esforzado responderé cualquiera pero no crees más usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es usar el método [getFile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#public-filedownloadtask-getfile-file-destinationfile). Este automáticamente moverá la descarga a un background thread. El argumento puede ser un `File` o una `Uri` pero asegurate de que el scheme de la uri sea `file`

```
songReference.getFile(destinationFile)
```

Habiendo aclarado que no necesitas usar corrutinas, si de todos modos vas a usarlas hazlo apropiadamente. Nunca uses `GlobalScope`. Tanto la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#global-scope) de android como la de kotlin recomiendan evitarlo. Incluso lo dice su misma descripción:

> Application code usually should use an application-defined CoroutineScope. Using async or launch on the instance of GlobalScope is highly discouraged.

Si te interesa entender mejor los motivos, lee el artículo titulado [The reason to avoid GlobalScope](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc) escrito por el Project Lead de Kotlin.

Y ese error que obtienes es porque efectivamente la descarga se está realizando en el main thread. Al especificar que use el dispatcher `Dispatchers.Main` la estás confinando al main thread.

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)
```

El dispatcher que deberías usar es `Dispatchers.IO`